# Sed / Regex Dynamic Replacements

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed

Back again with another sed / regex question.

I've been going through a lot of older php stuff converting it to 7.0 and there are a lot of just parameter swap changes I need to make with mysql -> mysqli.

I've already done a bulk change from mysql_query -> mysqli_query using sed but I still have to put the Sql Link Connection before the query in all of them. This is kinda tedious on 4k+ files and am trying to find a way to automate it.

IE I have a lot of :

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT sp FROM sp WHERE sp='$spid'",$sql3);  

$queryTwo = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sp WHERE sp = 'String'", $sql1);
```

That need to become:

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql3, "SELECT sp FROM sp WHERE sp='$spid'"); 

$queryTwo = mysqli_query($sql1, "SELECT * FROM sp WHERE sp = 'String'");
```

I have regex to find the ', $sqlx' or ',$sqlx' in given file here.

```
(\,.\$sql.|\,\$sql.)
```

I'm not sure how to go about bulk replacing something as dynamic as this with and google hasn't been much help. If there is something else I should use.  Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The solution below (provided by 123) :

```
sed 's/\(mysqli_query(\)\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\)/\1\3,\2/'
```

Works for 80% of the use cases, but I need to be able to force the swap on the last possible comma so lines like this:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE `services_exchange_publicfolder_addresses` SET `email`='$email', `member`='$member', `accesslevel`='$accesslevel', `accesslevel_new`='$accesslevel_new', `status`='$status', `step`='$step' WHERE `pkey`='$xid' LIMIT 1", $sql1);
```

Don't become like this:

```
mysqli_query( `member`='$member', `accesslevel`='$accesslevel', `accesslevel_new`='$accesslevel_new', `status`='$status', `step`='$step' WHERE `pkey`='$xid' LIMIT 1", $sql1,"UPDATE `services_exchange_publicfolder_addresses` SET `email`='$email');
```

Comment: So you just want to switch sides of the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question you could use sed

```
sed 's/\(mysqli_query(\)\([^,]*\), *\$\([^)]*\)/\1\3,\2/' file
```

or perl

```
perl -pe 's/mysqli_query\(\K([^,]*),\s*\$([^\)]*)/$2,$1/' file
```

prints

```
$query = mysqli_query(sql3,"SELECT sp FROM sp WHERE sp='$spid'");

$queryTwo = mysqli_query(sql1,"SELECT * FROM sp WHERE sp = 'String'");
```

Comment: op also wants to remome the `$` before `sqlN`.

Comment: That...

That is brilliantly simple, I have no idea why I didn't see it like that.

I blame brain fatigue, thank you so much.

Comment: Is there anyway to force this solution to only swap based around the LAST comma in the line? It seems to get bogged down and swap incorrectly when I have commas in between column names or variables.

Comment: @CodySavage It currently only swaps the first comma in `mysqli_query(...)`, if you need different behaviour then add the problematic lines to your question and I'll have a look.

Comment: Hi 123,

My apologies for not clarifying I do still want to keep the $. I'm editing my top comment to reflect that. An example of a line I have problems with is now included above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the input file really is, you should look for the correct fields to match. When your input has only 1 field in double quotes, you might use

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*"), *\$([^)]*)/\2, \1/' file
```